# Need to show a message on Prestashop product page if the price entered is wrong

Tags: prestashop

I have a website in Presta where user can enter custom price, there is a mix/max price from backend, now e.g. the max price is $50, i dont want people to add more than $50, currently they can, i checked with the developer of site, he says PS 1.7 loads product page content via ajax and he can not do this.
I was suggesting like we check price in validation and do some code there.
how can i do this in presta, any clue!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the template of your product page, using the min/max feature of an input type number in HTML5 :

```
<input type="number" name="price" min="1" max="50">
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is with html5, look documentation here : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/number

Regards

Comment: min and max functionality has already been added, what i want is that if a user enters price more than maximum, then i show him a warning message,

Comment: yas add jS ok look here : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/number#Validation

Comment: Ok close question please :)